# ArcGIS Online, Convert Geospatial PDF to kml or shp

Tags: google-maps, kml, arcgis-online, pdf, arcgis-rest-api

I have a client that wants to be able to upload Geospatial PDF documents and have them displayed as a KML layer on Google Maps. They have suggested using ArcGIS Online to accomplish this, however they are unsure of the process. I am able to upload these PDFs via the ArcGIS Online portal, but from there I am unable to do anything with them besides view the PDF.

So my questions are:

Is it possible to upload a Geospatial PDF to ArcGIS Online and convert it so it can be used as a KML layer?

Is there an easier alternative to convert these types of files to KML instead of uploading to ArcGIS Online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any method to convert the Geospatial PDF document to KML using any ArcGIS Online. To try to convert your Geospatial PDF to KML bypassing ArcGIS Online you might want to try this [tool](http://converter.mygeodata.eu/) that converts many types of GIS data to a prefered output.